# Order of intermediate operations

Tags: java, java-stream

Does the order in which the intermadiate functions are called have an impact on the performance of streams?

Example 1)

```
List<Item> myList = someItems;

myList.stream().filter(Item::isGreen).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Item::getSomeValue)).....
```

in comparison to

```
myList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Item::getSomeValue)).filter(Item::isGreen).....
```

Example 2)

```
myList.stream().filter(Item::isGreen).distinct()...
```

in comparison to

```
myList.stream().distinct().filter(Item::isGreen)...
```

Example 3)

```
 Stream.of(42,13,29,23,7,888).sorted().map(i -> new Item(i))...
```

in comparison to

```
Stream.of(42,13,29,23,7,888).map(i -> new Item(i)).sorted(Comaparator.comparingInt(Item::getSomeInt))..
```

i suppose with the first example it makes more sense to filter first, since it is not the whole list but a relatively shorter list that has to be sorted, depending on the filter afterwards.

but with the second and third one i'm not sure what the best order is? I'm not into some unnecessary or premature optimization, I'm just curious if the operations are called in the order they appear and if so if this has an impact on performance or if there is an optimised call internally in the compiler.

Comment: They're processed in order, even with a parallel stream iirc. Then it all depends on which function costs more: sorting or filtering? It depends on the implementation so better to have the fastest called first.

Comment: If you filter (and distinctify) before you sort, there will be fewer items to sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does matter.

##### Example 1

> i suppose with the first example it makes more sense to filter first, since it is not the whole list but a relatively shorter list that has to be sorted, depending on the filter afterwards.

Correct. Filtering elements out before sorting makes the sorting more performant and this can make a big difference if many elements are filtered out.

##### Example 2

This depends on the implementation of `Item` and what your data actually consists of. If `filter()` filters out many elements, you should put that before. However, if `isGreen` would be a costly operation and you had many duplicate elements, you sjould eliminate those duplicates at first.

##### Example 3

Sorting the `Integer` objects directly is likely more performant than getting the integer values of every element as tgis would habe to go through the `Comparator` while the `Integer` objects could directly be compared and the JIT could potentially do some more optimizations with the `Integer` objects. However, you might want to use `IntStream` so you can use the `int`s directly instead of caring about the wrapper objects and this could technically also use more sophisticated sorting algorithms like RadixSort.

##### In general

It is likely better to filter out elements before doing intensive operations like sorting.

Keep in mind that you shouldn't optimize prematurely (you seem to know that, though) and always test performance gains.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go through all the examples in detail.